# parsing excel sheet and calling appropriate functions

Tags: c#

I have an excel file with me. The contents of the excel file are as follows:-

```
RetVal      Function name

retVal1     ITemplate.GetAllTemplate
retVal2     ITask.GetTaskInstanceFromTemplate
retVal3     CreateTask
```

I need to write .NET application to parse the excel sheet and call the appropriate functions mentioned in the excel sheet. Can anyone help me? I don't know where to start. Kindly help me.

Comment: Your question seems a little vague. Swing by and look at [How To Use OleDb To Create Excel Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637918) to see if anything in that example can do what you are asking.

Comment: What's your problem ? Accessing the excel file ? call the function ? your architecture ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Is there some default namespace from where you'll find your functions? For any non-static functions you'll need to create an instance of the object, so how will you know what instance to create in the case of interfaces? (e.g. `ITemplate` and `ITask` can't create an instance to call their respective functions.)

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheFortin added extra details in the description. Please check above

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can refer some useful link to help you out...

Ok first, [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c) will help you to understand how to read data of an excel file.

Second, [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19911/Dynamically-Invoke-A-Method-Given-Strings-with-Met) will show you how to call the functions.

oh! Also, like @GuthMD told you in the comments, You won't be able to call function on type `ITemplate` and `ITask`. You will need to have the name of their implementations.

I hope I've answered your question and I'll edit my post if something is missing !