# CSV to DataTable via OleDbDataAdapter - C#

Tags: c#, sql, csv, datatable

I'm a bit new to C# and have been getting my feet wet.  I've been trying to figure out where I'm going wrong here.

What I'm attempting to do:  I'd like to import a CSV file into a data table.  I can do it easily with a simple "select * from file" query.  However when I try to make the query a little more complex I bump into an issue.

I more or less want to sort the DataTable by very specific equation.

Here's the code in question:

```
        static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

        string sql = @"SELECT name, max_sale_unit_price, max_offer_unit_price, " +
            "( (min_sale_unit_price * 0.85) - max_offer_unit_price ) AS thediff "+
            "FROM [" + fileName + "] " +
            "WHERE (min_sale_unit_price > 0) "+
            "AND ( ((min_sale_unit_price * 0.85) - max_offer_unit_price) > 2000 ) "+
            "ORDER BY thediff DESC";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

I do get an exception on "adapter.Fill(dataTable)" --> OleDB Exception:  No value given for one or more required parameters.  I have a feeling it's because I'm using the "AS thediff" keyword and attempting to sort by that.  What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: Why Can't you retrieve data by using "select * from file" query. I recommend you to bring the data using select query and then do whatever business implementation you need to do with your datatable. you can use linq which is less coding and easy or you can loop each datarow of your table and find data and implement.

Comment: That seems like a roundabout way to do it, no?  As a side note.  I've gotten the above code to work ... by commenting out the "ORDER BY" part. Surely this supports the Order by keywords?

Comment: but this is the best way to keep data in the form of object and if that data is in tabular structure then we can easily enumerate and get each data.

Comment: @RandDesu: Check out this question (with answer) I posted a while back - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10637918/153923

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Sorting the Datatable will return the EnumerableRowCollection<T>
```

Once datatable is with you you can use this LINQ for order by :

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> dr1 = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                             orderby row["your_column_name"] descending
                                        select row);

        // Dataview's ToTable returns the table 
        // Note : Don't use Dataview.Table method 

        DataTable dv = dr1.AsDataView().ToTable();
```

or you can use like this :

```
  DataTable dtSortedTable =  dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .OrderBy(row =>  row.Field<string>("your_column_name"))            
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```