# Microsoft Jet database engine It is already opened exclusively by another user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code.

```
private void CreateDBFFile()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

    using (OleDbConnection dbconnection = new OleDbConnection(connection))
    using (OleDbCommand command = dbconnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbconnection.Open();

        command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test (Id Integer, Changed Double, Name Text)";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My web.config file has connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn"
       connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=k:\temp1" 
       providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am trying to create a dbf file on my K drive. I keep getting an error on my dbConnection.Open() statement saying:

The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'k:\temp1'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

K:\ is not  a mapped drive. I gave network service userName to temp1 folder by going under security tab. I also gave modify rights to the Network service. Still keep getting this error. I also tried to put the entire above code in console application, that didn't work either. I keep getting the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `k:\temp1`? A file? A folder? I believe it would have to be a file in order to open a connection to it...

Comment: temp1 is a folder. I am trying to create a file in folder Temp1 and k: is just a drive like c:\ drive

Comment: `Mode=Share Deny None;` add that to your connection string

Comment: when I tried doing that  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=k:\temp1" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" Mode="Share" Deny="" None=""; />

  </connectionStrings> it is saying Mode attribute is not allowed

Comment: Are you trying to create an Excel file? [This question has a few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637918/215552).

Comment: access file, but I think the fle type does not matter